# Hive subquery with tuple

Tags: sql, hive, subquery

I write a query like:

```
SELECT corr_id
from `table1` 
WHERE  (corr_id, event_date) in 
    (SELECT (corr_id, event_date) FROM `table2` LIMIT 10)
LIMIT 10
```

However, I always get the error 'mismatched input 'SELECT' expecting ( near 'in' in expression specification'.

And this error message points to the subquery in third line.

I've tried this query in MySQL, it works.
Just wondering if hive supports such kind of query.

If NOT, anyone can help to figure out an elegant way to deal with that?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A query like this will work in hive

`select
a.corr_id
from table1 a, (select * from table2 limit 10)  b
where a.corr_id=b.corr_id 
and a.event_date=b.event_date
limit 10`